# php Wordpress plugin taxonomy category and posts sorting

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm using theme that have build-in Portfolio tab in the admin panel.
this theme using the portfolio items and portfolio categories instead of the original posts items and categories.

i've build a plugin that make list out of the portfolio's taxonomy - "categories"

```
<?php $portfolio_cats = get_terms( 'Categories', $args); ?>
    <?php foreach ($portfolio_cats as $cat) { echo "<option value = '".$cat->name."'>".$cat->name."</option>"; } ?> </select> <input style = "height: 35px;
```

and wanted to filter all the posts that are not related to the chosen category by the category's ID.

```
<input style = "height: 35px;
padding: 10px 45px;" type = "submit" value = "הצג" /> </form>
   <table class="widefat" style = "margin: 0 auto;width: 908px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $category_id = get_cat_ID(''.$_POST['filter'].'');
            $q = 'cat=' . $category_id;
            query_posts($q);
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <tr> <td> <?php echo $_POST['filter']; ?> </td> <td> <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </td> </tr>

           <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

but no matter what, its always show me the same original posts, and nothing from the portfolio's posts..

any help would really be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Its now showing every  portfolio item but, its showing it only at startup, when i choose category and run search filter, its showing nothing

```
<input style = "height: 35px;
padding: 10px 45px;" type = "submit" value = "הצג" /> </form>
   <table class="widefat" style = "margin: 0 auto;width: 908px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $category_id = $_REQUEST['filter'];
            /* $q = 'cat=' . $category_id; */
            query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $category_id, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'portfolio' ) );
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <tr> <td> <?php echo $_POST['filter']; ?> </td> <td> <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </td> </tr>

           <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Which post-type is that? Also what is `var_dump($args)` from the first code example?

Comment: post-type is portfolio. $args is nothing actually, it can be replaced with default attribute

Comment: Try with adding `post_type=portfolio` to the `$q` string. Otherwise `query_posts` will look in the default post-type (posts).

Comment: that worked, but Its showing now every portfolio item but, its showing them only at startup, when i choose catagory and run search filter, its showing nothing

Comment: so now you need to understand that the default categories are for the post-type "Post" (the default post-type). For the custom-post-types you have not categories but custom taxonomies. Look up in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) how to query the custom taxonomy that is used with the custom post type.

Comment: I was trying to look after a solution for 3 days, and I'm not the best with wordpress and php.. i found this document `http://richardsweeney.com/blog/wordpress-3-0-custom-queries-post-types-and-taxonomies/` but i'm having much problem have everything work...

Comment: Yes if it's something new for one, it takes some time until one figures out exactly how everything works. Normally you need to find out what exactly that plugin does to identify the post-type and the taxonomy. The rest is just querying it, normally querying it is then the easy part.

Comment: the purpose of the plugin is to sort the custom-portfolio-posts out of the portfolio catagories (taxonomy) named `catagories` .. i know that the custom-post is `portfolio`..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was sending a wrong key, instead of 'cat', it should be -> **categories**

```
query_posts( array ( 'categories' => $category_id, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'post_status' => publish, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```